# ¿Cómo puedo invocar un Servicio SOAP con WS-Security con WCF?

Tags: c#, soap, wcf

Estoy realizando un proyecto de facturación electrónica para Uruguay y estoy teniendo dificultades al poder enviar los documentos al servicio de DGI.
Actualmente estoy generando un cliente de consulta de RUT pero el resto de consultas y envíos se realizan de la misma manera, utilizando el estándar wss.
Esta es la única documentación que me proporcionaron para conectar mi cliente: http://www.efactura.dgi.gub.uy/files/web-services-consulta-de-rut?es
en donde se muestra como realizar pruebas con SoapUI el cual logre que funcionara pero no tengo para nada claro como pasar esto a mi sistema. El mismo está realizado en C# y obviamente la idea es utilizar WCF, les quedaría agradecido de por vida!!!!!
Les adjunto el Request y Response de SoapUI.

Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:dgi="DGI_Modernizacion_Consolidado" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-37419B5623AE3A46B515015148464721">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        <ds:Signature Id="SIG-37419B5623AE3A46B515015148464955" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                    <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="dgi soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                <ds:Reference URI="#id-37419B5623AE3A46B515015148464934">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="dgi" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </ds:Transform>
                   </ds:Transforms>
                   <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                       <ds:DigestValue>FpsfK1mvOormigiw7MQhnvGvveE=
                   </ds:DigestValue>
               </ds:Reference>
           </ds:SignedInfo>
           <ds:SignatureValue>mwm4ukovhs+pqjv6IDCrbi75UScikcsVceg8rHcjped+FeG9/tCFhvv4xiwrI0bnZON0R2zOs3PscuGokGs0DAzrQCr6aNt5QxR9SO8Do7YdBJ231t/4hwkGLojPXYWwJzZxVmu+SR6VzYdUNShMQrbAT+aApSa3JEizRnTS/439Cu9V0IbZF5Kj0nQWJoyKOeUNMuqOW+rRuRRTsRpde2NXpdGPV5L6o27O1ehqt2bxyKUQeaUe9MOCYZvpFqlM+fMunjxT1HqCgA2vx2i9otk4v7As8N+0UZSCDqkE4/ZH6h8rBkP0QEJTMepP1audXHitufi6zsWMOidnU/cX1w==</ds:SignatureValue>
           <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-37419B5623AE3A46B515015148464892">
               <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-37419B5623AE3A46B515015148464903">
                   <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-37419B5623AE3A46B515015148464721" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
               </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
           </ds:KeyInfo>
       </ds:Signature>
   </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-37419B5623AE3A46B515015148464934" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<dgi:WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial.Execute>
  <dgi:Rut>219999820013</dgi:Rut>
</dgi:WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial.Execute>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-4fd10e7a-93a2-48e5-8eab-0eedaef05dc9" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsu:Created>2017-07-08T15:48:38Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2017-07-08T15:53:38Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken wsu:Id="SecurityToken-9ceeac1c-5edf-4eb5-b637-e86614696faf" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
          <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
          <Reference URI="#Timestamp-4fd10e7a-93a2-48e5-8eab-0eedaef05dc9">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>cS5P2d5XmZRKZbNEupB9a+rpvx0=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
          <Reference URI="#Body-b429ff28-1f10-46c9-9789-1da737a531fd">
            <Transforms>
              <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <DigestValue>9osc7yXO1Ko46b3cwYbLdz0atKk=</DigestValue>
          </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>woPEsGhh3BNUgbBfMqbcmNip2qiY86pUt8TSjSANOPiKCpyQE9rSJ6n3uNcmuFbQuLblT4t9cyo5Vka2QREg6FzGeQXCsNXkTDalG2+gxWGfY40osrt2J5Yi75Oh8BFuXjE0TxkaGAAYkkXCK1T1b9xUGTaaZihP31n14PSt4hbz2zOhBSuCWh0H83WRibtyrKcdtMtR6+WxCPibRRBR5ZOP/F1k4A+n+Rna5fnSSxVobheZep8Yvg3tL1a+vl+NXgMxqHsrCywbcyQ+OoYxFQyb0BTIy1uCQBjBygEDOqv9V7qunrjpzin1YQGRDSRhHfQGy4PIf1l5kf0ZOQpODw==</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
          <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns="">
            <wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-9ceeac1c-5edf-4eb5-b637-e86614696faf" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
          </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </KeyInfo>
      </Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body wsu:Id="Body-b429ff28-1f10-46c9-9789-1da737a531fd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial.ExecuteResponse xmlns="DGI_Modernizacion_Consolidado">
      <Data>
        <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><WS_PersonaActEmpresarial xmlns="DGI_Modernizacion_Consolidado">
                   <RUT>219999820013</RUT>
                   <Denominacion>DGI RUC PRUEBA NO CEDE DISUELTA LEY 19.288</Denominacion>
                   <NombreFantasia>PRUEBA 3</NombreFantasia>
                   <TipoEntidad>38</TipoEntidad>
                   <DescripcionTipoEntidad>SC DISUELTA LEY 19288</DescripcionTipoEntidad>
                   <EstadoActividad>AA</EstadoActividad>
                   <FechaInicioActivdad>2004-04-22</FechaInicioActivdad>
                   <WS_DomFiscalLocPrincipal>
                    <WS_PersonaActEmpresarial.WS_DomFiscalLocPrincipalItem>
                        <Local_Sec_Nro>1</Local_Sec_Nro>
                        <Local_Nom_Fnt/>
                        <TipoLocal_Id>1</TipoLocal_Id>
                        <TipoLocal_Dsc>PRINCIPAL</TipoLocal_Dsc>
                        <Local_Fec_Ini>2004-04-22</Local_Fec_Ini>
                        <Local_Fec_Canc>0000-00-00</Local_Fec_Canc>
                        <TipoDom_Id>2</TipoDom_Id>
                        <TipoDom_Des>FISCAL</TipoDom_Des>
                        <CalOcup_id>0</CalOcup_id>
                        <Calocup_Des/>
                        <TerCod_Id>0</TerCod_Id>
                        <Tercod_Des/>
                        <Calle_id>605017</Calle_id>
                        <Calle_Nom>FERNANDEZ CRESPO AVDA. DANIEL</Calle_Nom>
                        <Dom_Pta_Nro>1534</Dom_Pta_Nro>
                        <Dom_Bis_Flg/>
                        <Dom_Ap_Nro>0</Dom_Ap_Nro>
                        <Loc_Id>2100000</Loc_Id>
                        <Loc_Nom>MONTEVIDEO</Loc_Nom>
                        <Dpto_Id>10</Dpto_Id>
                        <Dpto_Nom>MONTEVIDEO</Dpto_Nom>
                        <Dom_Pst_Cod>0</Dom_Pst_Cod>
                        <Dom_Coment/>
                        <Dom_Err_Cod>N</Dom_Err_Cod>
                        <Contactos>
                            <WS_Domicilio.WS_DomicilioItem.Contacto>
                                <TipoCtt_Id>5</TipoCtt_Id>
                                <TipoCtt_Des>TELEFONO FIJO</TipoCtt_Des>
                                <DomCtt_Val>59821344</DomCtt_Val>
                            </WS_Domicilio.WS_DomicilioItem.Contacto>
                        </Contactos>
                        <Complementos>
                        </Complementos>
                    </WS_PersonaActEmpresarial.WS_DomFiscalLocPrincipalItem>
                   </WS_DomFiscalLocPrincipal>
                   <WS_PersonaActividades>
                    <WS_PersonaActEmpresarial.WS_PersonaActividadesItem>
                        <GiroCod>84110</GiroCod>
                        <GiroNom>ACTIVIDADES DE LA ADMINISTRACION PUBLICA EN GENERAL</GiroNom>
                        <GiroFec_Ini>2004-04-22</GiroFec_Ini>
                    </WS_PersonaActEmpresarial.WS_PersonaActividadesItem>
                   </WS_PersonaActividades>
                 </WS_PersonaActEmpresarial>]]>
      </Data>
    </WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial.ExecuteResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Intente implementar el ejemplo que me sugiere M.Gress que le agradezco mucho la ayuda pero el problema es que no logro modificar dicho código para que se firme el mensaje.

PD.:Modifique el texto de Request ya que pude conseguir ver lo que envía SoapUI

Comment: Si tu sistema esta en c# me imagino que estas trabajando con Visual Studio, el cual te permite agregar Referencias de Servicios, desde tu proyecto al dar click derecho en tu solución te vas al apartado de Agregar, Referencia de Servicio y se te abrirá una asistente, pegas tu URL del servicio que deseas agregar y listo, te crea los archivos y configuraciones necesarias y puedes consumirlo creando una instancia de la clase que te crea.

Comment: Es lo que e primera instancia realice pero de igual manera no me funciono. Me da un error. Te dejo un link del manual. http://www.efactura.dgi.gub.uy/files/web-services-consulta-de-rut?es

Comment: ¿Qué error te manda?

Comment: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 'Error al consumir el Servicio Web'

Comment: Creo que este link te podria funcionar https://erickorlando.com/2016/01/21/invocar-un-servicio-soap-con-ws-security-a-travs-wcf/

Comment: Estoy observando el post pero claro tiene sus diferencias ya que en mi caso solo hay que firmar con el certificado x509 e insertar un Timestamp

Comment: Lograste hacer implementación para consumir los servicios web añadiendo al header el BinarySecurityToken con la Signature y el Timestamp de expiración?

Comment: Pudiste solucionar este tema ? tu sabes que estoy haciendo esta parte y me da el mismo error, te estaría sumamente agradecido si me puedes dar una mano. Saludos

Comment: Se pudo solucionar el inconveniente, me arroja el mismo error. Me contecte desde SOAPUI para realizar pruebas y me arroja el mismo error

Comment: El problema es que necesitamos tener una key.

Comment: estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo, tuviste exito ? podrias compartir el codigo con que lo conseguiste ?

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar con exito este consumo se necesita una KEY

WS-Security
Dado que la información es confidencial, el sistema incorpora una estrategia de seguridad basada en el estándar WSSecurity. Este estándar utiliza una infraestructura de clave pública (PKI o public key infraestructure).
El certificado a utilizar podrá ser un "Certificado Nominado de Persona Jurídica" o "Certificado Innominado de
Persona Jurídica" que al día de hoy solo emite el Correo del Uruguay (Única CA por lo pronto que formará parte de
PKI Uruguay). La decisión de cuál utilizar será resorte de cada Empresa/Organismo.
Una vez obtenido el certificado, deberá utilizarse el mismo para firmar digitalmente las consultas realizadas.
La manera más sencilla de trabajar con WS-Security es utilizando certificados almacenados en keystores.
Una vez obtenidos los certificados brindados por la autoridad certificadora, los keystores se pueden crear mediante la
herramienta Portecle, disponible en (http://portecle.sourceforge.net) o mediante openssl (http://www.openssl.org/).

fuente = [Guia SOAP Uruguay](https://www.efactura.dgi.gub.uy/files/web-services-consulta-de-rut?es)